# Why is SSE an objective function for KMeans++ when decreases with an increase in K

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

While I do think this to be obvious that, since the distances to the closest centre naturally reduces with an increase in K implying a reduction in SSE with larger K, I was wondering why this is considered an objective function. How can I decide on the right value of K, if for an increase in K, SSE is bound to decrease.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just realized, the intention is to plot these out, look for an elbow to be formed and then base your decision of K on that.